# API Login - Customer Community License

Tags: community, soap-api, partner-wsdl

I am trying to login as a "Customer Community" license user using Partner Wsdl and getting this error:

> [LoginFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_LOGIN'
>   exceptionMessage='Invalid username, password, security token; or user
>   locked out.']

The code works fine for "Partner Community" license users, API Enabled is checked for both the profiles. Also for the customer community user, Login history does not shows a new entry for an invalid login attempt.

I couldnt find any document saying SOAP API's or any API's are not allowed for Customer Community license users. Can someone please confirm.

Comment: make sure you are using password+securitytoken in SOAP request password section.

Comment: Ip's are whitelisted for that profile (0.0-255.255), so i dont think we need security token with this and it works with Partner profile with just passwords, in a same way.

Comment: @GulshanMiddha Did you resolve this? I am facing the exact same issue today!